# Calculate button is not working in android

Tags: android

I got the code of body mass index calculator calculator from [here](http://androiddiva.blogspot.in/) and I am trying to run in the eclipse the values are given and then calculate button is not working. Its showing the error unfortunately it has closed. Can any body will help in getting out of this.

here is the **logcat**

```
12-17 03:09:53.130: D/dalvikvm(872): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-17 03:09:58.120: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:09:58.850: D/gralloc_goldfish(872): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-17 03:10:59.470: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:31.400: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 391 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-17 03:11:38.210: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:38.450: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 294 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:38.680: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:39.870: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 181 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:40.300: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:40.440: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:40.920: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:42.270: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:44.000: D/dalvikvm(872): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 126K, 7% free 3058K/3260K, paused 60ms, total 71ms
12-17 03:11:44.090: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:44.370: W/ViewRootImpl(872): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_5, scanCode=6, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=283269, downTime=283269, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }

12-17 03:11:44.380: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(872): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.

12-17 03:11:44.380: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(872):   in android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer{b4d88ac0 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-99,85}

12-17 03:11:44.380: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(872):   0: sent at 283393000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_5, scanCode=6, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=283393, downTime=283269, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }

12-17 03:11:44.380: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 375 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:44.570: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:45.980: W/InputEventReceiver(872): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

12-17 03:11:45.990: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 501 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:46.040: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:52.680: W/TextView(872): TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.

12-17 03:11:52.680: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-17 03:11:54.850: D/AndroidRuntime(872): Shutting down VM

12-17 03:11:54.860: W/dalvikvm(872): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a69b90)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872): Process: com.example.bmi, PID: 872

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at 
java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.example.bmi.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)

12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-17 03:11:58.370: I/Process(872): Sending signal. PID: 872 SIG: 9
```

and here is the java

```
private Spinner heightspin;
private EditText feet;
private EditText cms;
private EditText lbs;
private TextView Lbstext;
private TextView result;
private RadioGroup rg;
private RadioButton radioSexButton;

public int hfeet;
public int hinc;
public int wlbs;
public int wkgs;
public int hcms;
public float bmifeet;
public float bmicms;
public String bmifeetStatus;
public String bmicmsstatus;
public int selectedId;
public String spintext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#c0c0c0")));
    heightspin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.heightspin);
    feet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feet);
    cms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cms);
    lbs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbs);
    Lbstext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Lbstext);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiosex);
    spintext = heightspin.getSelectedItem().toString();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.height_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    heightspin.setAdapter(adapter);
    heightspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                feet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cms.setHint("Inches");
                Lbstext.setText("Lbs");
                lbs.setHint("Lbs");
            } else {
                feet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cms.setHint("Cms");
                Lbstext.setText("Kgs");
                lbs.setHint("Kgs");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.claculate);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.claculate) {
                EditText feet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feet);
                EditText inches = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cms);
                EditText lbs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbs);

                result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                hfeet = Integer.parseInt(feet.getText().toString());
                hinc = Integer.parseInt(inches.getText().toString());
                wlbs = Integer.parseInt(lbs.getText().toString());

                selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                if (spintext.equalsIgnoreCase("Feet/Inches") && selectedId == R.id.radiomale) {
                    bmifeet = lbsbmi(hfeet, hinc, wlbs);
                    bmifeetStatus = staBMI(bmifeet);
                    result.setText("PRESENT STATUS :" + String.format("%.2f", bmifeet) + "-"
                            + bmifeetStatus);
                }
                if (spintext.equalsIgnoreCase("Feet/Inches") && selectedId == R.id.radiofemale) {
                    bmifeet = lbsbmi(hfeet, hinc, wlbs);
                    bmicmsstatus = fstaBMI(bmifeet);
                    result.setText("PRESENT STATUS :" + String.format("%.2f", bmifeet) + "-"
                            + bmicmsstatus);
                }
                if (spintext.equalsIgnoreCase("Cms") && selectedId == R.id.radiomale) {

                    bmicms = kgscbmi(hcms, wkgs);
                    bmifeetStatus = staBMI(bmicms);
                    result.setText("PRESENT STATUS :" + String.format("%.2f", bmicms) + "-"
                            + bmifeetStatus);
                }
                if (spintext.equalsIgnoreCase("Cms") && selectedId == R.id.radiofemale) {

                    bmicms = kgscbmi(hinc, wlbs);
                    bmicmsstatus = fstaBMI(bmicms);

                    result.setText("PRESENT STATUS :" + String.format("%.2f", bmicms) + "-"
                            + bmicmsstatus);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Put the values",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

private float lbsbmi(int feet, int inches, int lbs) {
    int inc = feet + (inches / 12);
    return (float) (lbs * 4.88 / (inc * inc));
}

private float kgscbmi(float cms, float kgs) {
    float hgt = cms / 100;
    return (float) (kgs / (hgt * hgt));
}

private String staBMI(float bmiValue) {
    if (bmiValue < 18.5) {
        return "Underweight";
    } else if (bmiValue < 25) {
        return "Normal";
    } else if (bmiValue < 30) {
        return "Overweight";
    } else {
        return "Obese";
    }
}

private String fstaBMI(float bmiValue) {
    if (bmiValue < 16.5) {
        return "Underweight";
    } else if (bmiValue < 22) {
        return "Normal";

    } else if (bmiValue < 27) {
        return "Overweight";
    } else {
        return "Obese";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the java code?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: paste `Logcat` as well as `JAVA` code

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

One (or all) of your `EditText`s is not a valid integer and is failing on `Integer.parseInt(String)`. You should handle any [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) and check the value of your `EditText`s (feet, inches, lbs).

---

**From your logcat:**

> 12-17 03:11:54.910: E/AndroidRuntime(872):
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

---

**Proposed fix:**

You could add the following method to your Activity class:

```
private int getIntFromEditText(EditText editText, int defaultValue) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString().trim());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

and then change

```
hfeet = Integer.parseInt(feet.getText().toString());
hinc = Integer.parseInt(inches.getText().toString());
wlbs = Integer.parseInt(lbs.getText().toString());
```

to

```
hfeet = getIntFromEditText(feet, 0);
hinc = getIntFromEditText(inches, 0);
wlbs = getIntFromEditText(lbs, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if those edittexts have blank values(i.e `""`) or not otherwise it will throw [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

add this

```
String hFeetStr = feet.getText().toString().trim();
String hincStr = inches.getText().toString().trim();
String wlbsStr = lbs.getText().toString().trim();

if(hFeetStr != null && !hFeetStr.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    hfeet = Integer.parseInt(hFeetStr);
else
    hfeet = 0;
if(hincStr != null && !hincStr.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    hinc = Integer.parseInt(hincStr);
else
    hinc = 0;
if(wlbsStr != null && !wlbsStr.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    wlbs = Integer.parseInt(wlbsStr);
else
    wlbs = 0;
```

instead of

```
hfeet = Integer.parseInt(feet.getText().toString());
hinc = Integer.parseInt(inches.getText().toString());
wlbs = Integer.parseInt(lbs.getText().toString());
```

Comment: tried as the way you said but it is not calculating after entering the values it is just displaying the toast please put the values

Comment: where u check selected item of `RadioGroup` those conditions are *false* debug ur code why those conditions are *false*